# How to update the entire Anaconda Python distribution offline in Windows?

Tags: python, installation, updates, anaconda

I use Anaconda Python distribution on a Windows machine without Internet access.

The installation is extremely easy: just download and copy the Anaconda Windows installer and install in standard way.

But when it comes to updating:

- If I manually download, copy, and update individual packages, it is tedious and prone to error, considering the complicated interdependency among packages.
- If I uninstall the entire Anaconda and then reinstall a new one (my current approach), I'll lose my personal configurations as well as manually installed packages that are not included in Anaconda installer.

Is it possible to run something like:

```
conda update Anaconda-2.2.0-Windows-x86_64.exe
```

to extract and update necessary packages from the all-in-one Windows installer?

I notice the new `--offline` option provided by the latest `conda update` command, but it doesn't seem to serve for this purpose...

Answer (score 8):

In general, things like [Anaconda Server](http://continuum.io/anaconda-server) are designed to make this sort of workflow easier.

Some suggested workarounds:

- Reproduce your install on another machine with internet (save `conda list --export` to a file and `conda install --file`). Then use `conda update` on that machine to generate and download the packages. One tip that could be helpful is if you take several conda packages and tar them up into a flat tarball you can use conda to install that tarball and it will install all the packages. Or you can put the packages in the `pkgs` cache and use the `--offline` flag.
- Install the newer Anaconda to a different location and copy the packages from the `pkgs` cache to your current folder.

Both of these are a bit clunky, but there's no easy way to achieve this without Anaconda Server.

Comment: The `pkgs` cache trick seems quite useful. Thank you for mentioning that~